# How to query Cosmos DB and get a boolean value if the item exists

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

My data in Cosmos DB is like this:

```
{    
  id:1,    
  key:"USA",  
  states:["New York","New Jersey", "Ohio", "Florida" ]         
}
```

I want to check if a state exists in the document. Ex: "California". If it exists, then I want to return true otherwise false. Can someone help me with the query that fetches me a boolean value.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. When you changed it to ask about C#, you completely changed the meaning of the question (which I had already answered). Feel free to post a new question regarding your specific C# challenge.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use `ARRAY_CONTAINS()`. Typically, you'd use it in your `WHERE` clause, but you can also just return the boolean directly. In your example, you'd do something like:

```
SELECT ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.states, "California")
FROM c
```

This results in something like:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "key": "USA",
        "$1": true
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "key": "USA",
        "$1": false
    }
]
```

You can also return other properties along with the boolean:

```
SELECT c.id, c.key, ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.states, "California")
FROM c
```

And if you want to make sure you have the array defined for properties you check:

```
SELECT c.id, c.key, ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.states, "California")
FROM c
WHERE IS_DEFINED(c.states)
```

Lastly: You can alias the boolean, so that it returns an actual property name instead of something like `$1`:

```
SELECT c.id, c.key,
ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.states, "California") AS ContainsCalifornia
FROM c
WHERE IS_DEFINED(c.states)
```

And you'd get something back like:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "key": "USA",
    "ContainsCalifornia": true
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "key": "USA",
    "ContainsCalifornia": false
}
```

Comment: Thanks David for quick response. Sorry my question was not clear. My actual question is how can I query from c#?

Comment: That... is not really a good thing to do, changing the entire context of your question. I answered what you asked, in detail, with examples. Your question had nothing to do with C# (and that edit should be rolled back, as it's a completely different question now). FYI via `CreateDocumentQuery()` you can just pass the entire query string (or parameterize it) and test exactly what I've provided to you. Plenty of examples for making SQL queries. Then, if you're struggling still, you can ask a new question, showing what you've attempted in C#, expected vs actual output, etc.